# Implementation feature of character shorthand \s

Tags: regex, erlang

I am wondering why in Erlang in the regex library [re](http://erlang.org/doc/man/re.html), the character shorthand `\s` only selects a whitespace (`32` ASCII  character) and is not the equivalent of `[ \\t\\n\\r]` regular expression.

At the same time, the "anti-pattern" for `\s` - `\S`(Non-space character shorthand) implements predictable behavior.

###### Test labs

- [EUnit tests](https://github.com/rustkas/Introducing-Regular-Expressions-by-Erlang/blob/main/code/ch02/ex01_rime_intro/lib/lib_02_simple_pattern_matching/test/tests_09_whitespace_01_tests.erl) for `\s`.
- [EUnit tests](https://github.com/rustkas/Introducing-Regular-Expressions-by-Erlang/blob/main/code/ch02/ex01_rime_intro/lib/lib_02_simple_pattern_matching/test/tests_09_whitespace_02_tests.erl) for `[ \\t\\n\\r]`.
- [EUnit tests](https://github.com/rustkas/Introducing-Regular-Expressions-by-Erlang/blob/main/code/ch02/ex01_rime_intro/lib/lib_02_simple_pattern_matching/test/tests_10_whitespace_tests.erl) for `\S`.

Comment: Never used it but the docs in the first link says _"For compatibility with Perl, \s did not used to match the VT character (code 11), which made it different from the the POSIX "space" class. However, Perl added VT at release 5.18, and PCRE followed suit at release 8.34. The default \s characters are now HT (9), LF (10), VT (11), FF (12), CR (13), and space (32), which are defined as white space in the "C" locale."_ Are you saying that the behavior you're experiencing contradicts what's mentioned in the docs?

Comment: Yes. It turns out so. I've verified this with tests.

Comment: I am currently testing the work of the Erlang [re](http://erlang.org/doc/man/re.html) library, reading the documentation and sharing my findings. If someone, a more experienced Erlang programmer, will tell us something valuable - why this is so, I will be glad.

Comment: I went back as far as Erlang/OTP R14B04 and ran your `tests_09_whitespace_01_tests:research_test/0` function, which tests `\s` against all values 0-255, and for that OTP version and every major release since then, it printed out out that it found 9, 10, 12, 13, and 32, and then starting at version 20.0 it also included 11 as a match. This matches the documentation and the comment by @41686d6564 . I have `LC_ALL=C` set in my environment. I suggest checking your locale settings.

Comment: @SteveVinoski, thank you for the clue! I run tests with Erlang/OTP 24. I checked my locale. `LC_ALL` is not set up. What value should be set in the variable `LC_ALL` in order to get the declared value in the documentation and working with Unicode too? I would very much like to have the correct system settings from the point of view of the developers of the [re](http://erlang.org/doc/man/re.html) library.

Comment: It is convenient for me to study work on Erlang on Windows 7. Maybe this is the case? Maybe on Windows I get such results. I haven't tried running my tests on Linux-based operating systems yet.

Answer (score 1):

I still found the answer to my question in the documentation of the [re](http://erlang.org/doc/man/re.html) library.

> For compatibility with Perl, \s did not used to match the VT character
> (code 11), which made it different from the the POSIX "space" class.
> However, Perl added VT at release 5.18, and PCRE followed suit at
> release 8.34. The default \s characters are now HT (9), LF (10), VT
> (11), FF (12), CR (13), and space (32), which are defined as white
> space in the "C" locale. This list may vary if locale-specific
> matching is taking place. For example, in some locales the
> "non-breaking space" character (\xA0) is recognized as white space,
> and in others the VT character is not.

From this, I conclude that the expected work with is possible so only if there is a set locale value - "C".

Now I understand why everything works this way - it was conceived by the developers, that is, we need to take this feature into account when implementing regular expressions in Erlang.

Answer (score 1):

To overcome the implementation limitations (related to the need to take into account the locale value), I implemented a project to be able to adapt the regular expression text to the available capabilities of my software (my operating system does not have the required parameter set of locale, but I would like to continue using it).

This is a helper library [re_tuner](https://hex.pm/packages/re_tuner).